# wp_register_style and internal server error

Tags: php, css

When I try to enqueue custom-css.php I get error 500. Here is complete code:

```
function custom_style() {
wp_register_style('custom-style',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom-style.php', array(), '20152111');
wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_style' );
```

And here is custom-style.php file:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/css'); ?>
<style>
    body.single-post{
    background:url(<?php echo esc_url($custombck); ?>) no-repeat center top !important;
    background-size: contain !important;
    background-position-y: -30% !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try leaving the file named custom-style.css and add a .htaccess file to the same folder as the css file.

```
<FilesMatch "^.*?style.*?$">
SetHandler php5-script
</FilesMatch>
```

Now you can use php inside of your css file instead. This should work.

Comment: That would be the case with basic stylesheet, but I need to include php code in css, that's why I have custom-style.php

Comment: Okay I did not understand what you were trying to do. I get it now. I revised my answer.